# How do I assign a function to the window object while using an ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I am working with a third-party script, and I need to assign some functions to the window object, so that those functions are available to that third-party script (which will be running in the same browser window, called from the same domain). I must do this using ES6, using `let` and modules (`import` / `export`).

In ES5, I can do this:

```
//index.html
<script src="main.js"></script>
//third-party script will use window.myObj.blurt()
<script src="third-party-script.js"></script>
```

```
//main.js
var myObj = {};

myObj = {
  blurt: function(){
    console.log("Hello."); 
  }
}
```

`blurt()` is now available to be invoked off of the `window` object. I can put this in my browser console, and it will work: `window.myObj.blurt()`.

I would like to do this, in ES6:

```
//index.html - note the type="module"
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
//third-party script will use window.myObj.blurt()
<script src="third-party-script.js"></script>
```

```
//main.js
import './my-window-functions.js';

//other existing code
```

```
//my-window-functions.js - NOT the third-party script - just my ES6 module system
let myObj = {};

myObj = {
  blurt: function(){
    console.log("Hello.");
  }
}
```

Now `window.myObj.blurt()` is `undefined`. How do I assign functions to the `window` object in this ecosystem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `my-window-functions.js` you need to export the `myObj`.

```
let myObj = {};

    myObj = {
      blurt: function(){
        console.log("Hello.");
      }
    }
export {myObj};
```

Then in your `main.js` you need to import the `myObj` and assign it to the window object manually.

```
import { myObj } from'./my-window-functions.js';

window.myObj  = myObj;
```

Then your 3rd party script can use the `window.myObj.blurt()`.

Comment: `Object.assign(window, { myObj })` is a bit cleaner and allows for snippet automation.